# Unable to deserialize JSON to a Dictionary<string, List<string>> using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, casting, javascriptserializer

I have issues deserializing JSON in my c# code using the JavaScriptSerializer library.

Here is my sample JSON:

> {"A":["a","b","c","d"],"B":["a"],"C":[]}

I am using a Dictionary to hold the JSON as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myObject;
```

This is how I parse the JSON and cast it to my object:

```
myObject= (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)jsc.DeserializeObject(json);
```

However, at runtime, the previous line throws a Casting exception as follows

> Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]
>   to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]]

For some reason the `JavaScriptSerializer` cannot recognize the JSON Array having strings as a `List<string>`

**UPDATE**

I populated my `Dictionary` data structure with some hardcoded strings to see what is the serialized version. It turns out to be exactly what my input JSON string is.

Comment: What happens if you define myObject using var instead of explicitly as a Dictionary?

Comment: @Necoras That did not work either :(

Comment: @sjokkogutten has the right answer, but the error message does tell you why an exception is being thrown, the `DeserializeObject` method is returning a `Dictionary<string,object>` and you are then trying to cast it to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Even if the generic types you are closing over can be casted, it doesn't meant he generic type itself can be. For instance, you can't cast `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>`, even though string does inherit from object. Generics don't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `DeserializeObject` method, use the generic `Deserialize<T>` method and specify `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` as the type argument.  Then it will work correctly:

```
string json = @"{""A"":[""a"",""b"",""c"",""d""],""B"":[""a""],""C"":[]}";

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

Dictionary<string, List<string>> myObject = 
    serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in myObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
}
```

Output:

```
A: a,b,c,d
B: a
C:
```

Comment: This works!! Thanks!
For some reason, I completely missed that method. I thought this was the same as JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize Method (String, Type). Stupid me.

Comment: No problem; glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is casting to a `List<string>`
If casting to an object is acceptable, you could do it like this:

```
string json = "{\"A\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"],\"B\":[\"a\"],\"C\":[]}";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedValues = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
```

I would also recommend looking into [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which does a much better job at serializing/deserializing

Comment: You can even use the generic `Deserialize` method and specify the same type as you're looking for. That way you wouldn't have to do any casting in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Type based on the JSON structure and then use the Type in the Serialization or DeSerialization like this.

I create the RootObject from the JSON using functionality found in the Web Essentials Visual Studio Extension.

```
public class JSONSerializer
{
    public void RunIt()
    {
        string json = "{\"A\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"],\"B\":[\"a\"],\"C\":[]}";

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        Rootobject jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);

        Console.Write(serializer.Serialize(jsonObject));
    }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] A { get; set; }
    public string[] B { get; set; }
    public object[] C { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this method directly. I do not know the number of key/array pairs that will be present in the RootObject.